# Are all hyper-algebraic numbers algebraic?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

I know an **algebraic number** is any complex number that is a root of a non-zero polynomial in one variable with rational coefficients (or equivalently – by clearing denominators – with integer coefficients).

So Let  **hyper-algebraic** number
 be any complex number that is a root of a non-zero polynomial in one variable with **algebraic coefficients** 


**My question**   : are all hyper-algebraic numbers algebraic ?

---

*for example :* 

let define $x_0$ as the root of 
  $x^5+x=10$
 something like $x_0≈1.53301...$


**I wonder** :

if $y_0$ is any root of $y^5+x_0^2y=(1+{\sqrt x_0})$  (this polynomial has algebraic coefficients)
then 
is $y_0$ algebraic ? 
I mean is there any polynomial with integer coefficients (may be we cannot find it , but it exists ) that  $y_0$ is its root ?

Comment: Yes. This should be in any textbook that covers basic field theory. It might be expressed in the form: An algebraic extension of an algebraic extension of a field $K$ is an algebraic extension of $K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field of algebraic numbers $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is algebraically closed. Therefore every root of a polynomial with algebraic coefficients is also algebraic.

Reference: Corollary $1.4$ [here](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/361/lectures/lec09.pdf).